# Unable to offer bounty

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounties

I am trying to offer a bounty on [this two-year-old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641818/working-of-the-c-preprocessor), but I get as far as the popup asking me to choose an amount of rep... and then the "Next" button is a no-op.

I have only tried with 50 and 100 selected, as I do not wish to risk accidentally *actually* offering any more than that if the request unexpectedly decides to go through at higher rep values.

Is my browser borked or did something happen to bounties?

Comment: Works for me. How much do you want to offer :)

Comment: @sehe: _All of your rep_. I'll pay you back, honest!

Comment: What browser are you even using?

Comment: Works for me too

Comment: Firefox 18.0.2, with no notable extensions, except a bit of Greasemonkey.. hmm..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this was being caused by [the "SE Modifications" Greasemonkey script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a); no version information appears to be available for such scripts, but I'd installed it at least a year ago.

It hasn't had this effect before, so that version of the script interacts poorly with something about the code for the new dialogs.

I updated the script and everything now seems to be fine.

Comment: Good to be reminded why I'm against fancy scripts breaking stuff unexpectedly. Good catch! :-)