# Bug in textarea in bounty creation popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounties, firefox

I was attempting to create a bounty for a question over on Stack Overflow and ran into a rendering glitch on the last page. After entering a sentence that exceeds the length of a single line, the popup contents scroll slightly to the right and strange characters start showing up:

[image]

There is no '(' in my sentence so it's strange that it's showing up in the textarea. When you move the cursor it around the line edge, the textarea scrolls from right to left and back.

Here's what I've got:

- Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit
- Firefox 18.0.2

This is also occurring on Firefox 24.0 on Windows 7 Enterprise Service Pack 1.

[image: Glitch-like behavior in textarea]

The data entry starts out fine:

[image: No issue after 1.5 lines of text]

Then it goes all wacky as I complete the second line:

[image: Scrolling Right]

Comment: +1 I saw this too whilst debugging http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167972/unable-to-offer-bounty. Same browser, but Win7. Note that, on submission, the actual custom message used is "correct" and unmangled.

Comment: There's actually a second textarea that contains the default message, which contains the parenthesis you're seeing. The rendering is all sorts of crazy there.

Comment: Opera and safari seem fine, confirmed on Firefox 22 (OSX)

Comment: Chrome 28.0.1500.63 on Ubuntu 13.04 is fine.

Comment: Confirmed Firefox 22 on Win XP, Chrome is fine. **Please fix this issue, it annoys me every time.** Nathan, maybe the word "glitch" in the title was causing others to consider this a minor issue? I have edited the question a little.

Comment: @Tomas you can always start a bounty to help fix this bug in bounty... :-)

Comment: Also happening on Firefox 23.

Comment: @Tomas +1 for the bounty message, lol!

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the bounty :-) What, you hadn't +1 already before!!?? :-DD

Comment: @NathanOsman I can reproduce this on Firefox 22 for Windows 7, on both SO and a beta site ([money.SE])

Comment: I get this all the time also.  Usually using Firefox.

Comment: This is still not fixed? I got the bug as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've removed the overflow style from the div.

With you in the next build.

Comment: So Ilmari should expect a paycheck soon? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this bug is caused by the `overflow: hidden` style attribute on the `<div>` tag that encloses the bounty form:

[image: Screenshot]

Simply disabling this style using the Firefox developer tools (or using a user style) is enough to fix the bug, and appears to have no harmful side effects.

This bug does not occur on Chrome, because, instead of clipping the contents of the inner div, it expands the surrounding popup div.  Even on Chrome, though, removing the `overflow: hidden` style improves the appearance of the popup by getting rid of the excessive right margin.

Note that, with or without the fix, I'm unable to reproduce some of the more egregious symptoms of this bug described above, such as the mysteriously appearing parentheses.  Based on the comments, it seems likely that these symptoms were due to interactions of this bug with an old implementation of the placeholder text, which has since been replaced by a standard `placeholder` attribute on the textarea.

**Update:** Version 1.16 of the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script now includes a CSS rule to override this `overflow: hidden` style.