# Bounty custom message less than 30 characters breaks dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, bounty-remarks

There's a strange edge case when adding custom bounty messages. An empty message is allowed, but if you do type a message, it must be at least 30 characters:

[image]

If you try to submit a non-empty message less than 30 characters, the "Start Bounty" button is disabled, and nothing happens:

[image]

The button never re-enables, even if you fix the message:

[image]

Comment: there was a dupe somewhere...

Comment: @nicael nope, that's a new one. Maybe you remember [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167975/bug-in-textarea-in-bounty-creation-popup) which lived for long time, drawing tons of reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming to you in the next build: a re-enabled button and an error message to go with it.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: But why did it break in the first place? What have you changed? :)

Comment: @Shadow As far as I know, it's been that way a long time. Possibly always?

Comment: Hard to believe, I always click submit buttons to see what happens (before I should click them), disabled or not, and I had my share of bounties.

Comment: [day-one bug](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/104761/31260)?

Comment: How did that _ever_ work? Oh, wait, it didn't :)